# Where did the usage of bury in "bury a jumper" come from?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, etymology

I heard the phrase "bury a jumper" in an NBA game. I googled it, and found:

According to [this site](https://www.dummies.com/sports/fantasy-sports/fantasy-basketball/basketball-terms-and-phrases-to-know/#:%7E:text=deuce%3A%20A%20made%20field%20goal%2C%20worth%20two%20points.):

> bury a jumper: To make an especially pretty jump shot.

According to [Merriam-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bury), here bury means:

> sports : to succeed emphatically or impressively in making (a shot)

I'm curious about where did this usage of bury come from? How does it relate to the word's originial meaning?

Comment: I'd guess the metaphoric element here derives from earlier idiomatically established usages like ***burying the ball in the net*** (basketball), or ***...in the goalmouth*** (soccer) or ***in the pocket*** (snooker). I don't follow basketball, but a "jumper" sounds like a natural usage for "shot the requires player to jump high".

Comment: *”We have lots of different ways of describing goals in football and when a player really strikes the ball hard and gives the keeper no chance we can say that **the player has buried the ball in the back of the net***  -  he or she has scored with a really hard shot. Of course, the verb ‘to bury‘ means to put something in the ground and so in football the suggestion is that if a player buries the ball in the back of the net, the ball is not coming back; it is an emphatic goal and the keeper and defence can do nothing about it.*” https://languagecaster.com/football-language-bury-ball-back-net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many times in sports, the lingo is very, very complicated if you don't know the slang of the place and very idiomatic English.

A **jumper** stands for a **jump shot** in basketball.

Bury here means to shove it or push into or through the basket so that it **cannot not go** through it.

Bury a jumper: execute a clean jump shot.

(Also, in sports lingo, when you win over an opponent, you can be said to bury them).